# docker и -v: как понять, монтиируется с хоста в контейнер или наоборот?

Tags: docker

Я долго мучался с докером, и понял, что даже после прочтения документации и ответов на частые вопросы не понимаю вот чего.

Вот пример команды:

```
docker run --name=nginx -d -v ~/nginxlogs:/var/log/nginx -p 5000:80 nginx
```

Про эту команду пишут, что она возьмет логи энджинкса и смонтирует их мне в ~/nginxlogs.

Но здесь же нигде не указывается "направление монтирования". С тем же успехом я могу ожидать, что команда возьмёт мою директорию ~/nginxlogs и засунет её в контейнер.

Есть ещё команда --mount, которая тоже позволяет указать source, destination — но никак не "направление монтирования"

Не могли бы Вы объяснить мне этот момент? То есть, как надо монтировать фолдеры "с хоста в контейнер" и "из контейнера на хост" и какими командами (или ключами) для этого правильно пользоваться?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В текущем контексте можно считать, что монтирование командами `-v` и `--mount` всегда происходит **в направлении из docker-хоста в docker-контейнер**. Если же ты хочешь расшарить имеющуюся папку из контейнера в хост, то тут нужны уже совсем другие средства.
В твоём случаем команда

```
  docker run --name=nginx -d -v ~/nginxlogs:/var/log/nginx -p 5000:80 nginx
```

будет давать доступ контейнеру к хостовой папке `~/nginxlogs`, но под видом `/var/log/nginx`. Конечно, это упрощённое объяснение. Соответственно, если в твоём образе контейнера уже была папка `/var/log/nginx` с каким-либо непустым содержимым, то контейнер не увидит это содержимое при запуске в такой конфигурации.

**Более подробно:**
На самом деле docker сначала создаёт том (**volume**), который *может быть* основан на папке хоста, а уже потом монтирует его к контейнеру (или нескольким контейнерам). Отсюда всегда строгое направление монтирования: из хоста в контейнер. `docker run -v` можно рассматривать как сокращение, т.е. создание тома + запуск контейнера со смонтированным томом в одной команде.

Если по каким-либо причинам необходимо смонтировать уже имеющиеся файлы/папки из контейнера в хост-систему, что по моему мнению немного извращение, то тут надо использовать уже другие средства, которые на сам docker никак не завязаны. К примеру, монтирование удалённых(сетевых) папок в linux. Возможно есть какие-то плагины docker'а, которые облегчат данную работу, но я тут сказать ничего не могу.

Comment: Приветствую! Большое спасибро за объяснение! Правильно ли я понимаю, что вот в этом вот руководстве просто написана чушь? https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-share-data-between-the-docker-container-and-the-host

Comment: @S.H. Там одна не совсем точная формулировка, которая может ввести в заблуждение. Хотя я не носитель английского языка, потому моё мнение не совсем авторитетно.  P.S. Всегда вначале смотри [официальную документацию](https://docs.docker.com/storage/). Там хоть и больше букв, но академичность изложения гораздо выше.

Comment: Да, я написал этот вопрос после того, как прочитал официальную документацию, её перевод в паре мест и вот этот пост на DO. и на DO написано нечто противоположное всему остальному. Нельзя ли мне еще на два маленьких вопроса ответить: что это за не совсем точная формулировка? и какими средствами следует расшаривать фолдеры из контейнера наружу? Если Вы дадите мне ключевые слова для поиска - я дальше сам могу...

Comment: @S.H. Сначала создаётся docker-том (volume), который может быть основан на папке хоста. А потом он монтируется к контейнеру (а может и к нескольким). `docker run -v` - это сокращённый вариант типа) Отсюда всегда строгое направление монтирования. Если же тебе надо зашарить существующие только в контейнере файлы на хост, что по-моему мнению немного извращение, то тебе придётся это делать также, как в linux'е монтируются удалённые папки. Какие docker-плагины так могут я не знаю.

Comment: Короче, понятно. Это я всё тоже читал. НИГДЕ, я еще раз говорю - НИГДЕ не говорится, что вот эта вот фигота с созданием тома работает именно так и позволяет увидеть файловую сситему внутри контейнера. Если у Вас найдется минтука - можете добавить эту инфу в Ваш прекрасный ответ

Comment: Я немного подумал, и всё понял, кажется. Короче, всегда монтируется том из хоста в контейнер. Потом, после этого монтирования, контейнер может что то в этот том писать. Тогда мы на хосте увидим эти файлы и т.п. Если не надо, чтобы контейнер мог что то поменять на хосте - тогда монтируем в read only режиме